# How can i give the player a random block ? Thanks! (Minecraft Forge Modding 1.15)

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

i want that the Player gets a random block everytime he holds a bedrock block (only an example, later I want  to do way more cooler Things) I coded it that something happens when the Player is Holding a bedrock block. But I dont know how to give the Player a random block... Thanks for your help!

Code:

```
           package com.kelbig.mod.events;

import com.kelbig.mod.FirstMod;

import net.minecraft.entity.LivingEntity;
import net.minecraft.item.Items;
import net.minecraft.util.text.StringTextComponent;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.FOVUpdateEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus;



@Mod.EventBusSubscriber (modid = FirstMod.MOD_ID, bus = Bus.FORGE)
public class RightClickBlock {  


    @SubscribeEvent 
    public static void on(FOVUpdateEvent event) {



        if(player.getHeldItemMainhand().getItem() == Items.BEDROCK) 
        {           
                        event.setNewfov(event.getFov() * 1.3F); 
                 }       

}
```

Comment: There's two parts to this: how to select a random block type, and how to give a block of a specified type to a player. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Hello, im stuck by "how to select a random block type". Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Item::getItemById` uses the item registry to get an item. The registered `Item`s seem to be stored in an iterator. `Block` has a similar registry. That we can use.

Something like this might work:

```
Iterator<Block> itemIterator = Registry.BLOCK.iterator(); // Gets the registry iterator
ArrayList<Block> blockList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Iterator<Block> it = itemIterator; it.hasNext(); ) // Iterates through registry iterator
{
    blockList.add(it.next()); // Adds each element to a List (easier to get a random element from)
}

Random rand = new Random();
Block randomBlock = blockList.get(rand.nextInt(blockList.size())); // Chooses a random element from the List of Blocks
```

You can then do all kinds of stuff with the `Block`. To get it in `Item` format do `Item itemFromRandomBlock = randomBlock.asItem()`.

This is untested. I'm not too familiar with 1.15 modding, but it looks like it will work.

Comment: YES! It did work after changing      List<Block> itemList = new ArrayList<>();         to ArrayList<Block> itemList = new ArrayList<>();   Do you also know how to get the coordinates of a block the Player is loocking at? I tried something like that: double x = Player.getloockvec().getX;  double y Player.getloockvec().getY; double z = Player.getloockvec().getZ; but somehow These coordinates are Always between 0, 0, 0, and 1,1,1 so i did not get the blocks coordinates…  ( And thanks so far!)

Comment: or how can I place the randomBlock ? sorry, i thougt something like  worldIn.setBlockState(new BlockPos(player.getPosition().down()), randomBlock );  would work...

Comment: @Kelbig I see you asked another question about this, so could you please update it with what you've tried and then I can take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598428/hello-i-want-the-block-on-which-the-player-looks-turns-into-a-bedrock-block-but

Comment: Hello @TheKingElessa could you help me with that? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717481/how-can-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-block-the-player-is-looking-at)